# SP2013: which AAM I need to put in content source starting addresses?

Tags: content-source

According to [Microsoft best practice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn535606%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BKMK_UseContentSources): When you crawl the default zone of a SharePoint web application, the query processor automatically maps and returns search-result URLs so that they are relative to the alternate access mapping (AAM) zone from which queries are performed.

In our SP2013 farm there is a web application with two AAM on default zone:

```
Internal URL                     Zone                      Public URL for Zone
https://web.domain.com          default                  https://web.domain.com
https://web01               default               https://web.domain.com
https://web             Intranet                  https://web
http://web01                Internet                  https://web01
```

My questions are:

1. Should I put both `https://web.domain.com` and `https://web01` in content source? Would it make the crawler crawl the same content twice (waste system resources)?
2. What should be my Server Name Mappings setup in above case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1:** As per your AAM, You need to add `https://web.domain.com` into your content source.

**2:** In that case you dont need any server mapping as you are using the FQDN.

We have same kind of setup in our farm due to some network issues, So i recommend what we are using.

If you click on the edit public url, you will see the FQDN in your default zone and this is what you want.

Comment: Do you mean in content source, we ALWAYS refer to Public URL of default zone? The Internal URL doesn't matter?

Comment: public url is the first one in the list, if you have more than 1 url in the one zone then first one will count.